# Ionic Sort multi dimension array

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, ionic-framework

i have a 2D array that i want to sort by a certain value, here's my array:

```
[
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "Trsttzp",
      "Prix": "45",
      "Date": "01/12/2018"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "Trst",
      "Prix": "65",
      "Date": "01/13/2018"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "Ts",
      "Prix": "99",
      "Date": "01/02/2018"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "Ts",
      "Prix": "99",
      "Date": "01/12/2018"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "Haa",
      "Prix": "55",
      "Date": "01/12/2018"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Categorie": "Alimentation",
      "Label": "qsd",
      "Prix": "6",
      "Date": "01/12/2018"
    }
  ]
]
```

i want to sort it by Date, i tried to use "fast-sort" library from npm but it doesnt seem to work, i think that the problem is that this library doesnt work with 2d arrays, and i can't find a way to do it with typescript or a libriary that supports 2d arrays :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough just do it like this without a 3rd party lib

`let arraysorted = array.sort((x,y) => new Date(x[0].Date) > new Date(y[0].Date));`